# android app doesn't install after an apk edit

Tags: android

I am running Marshmallow 6.0.1 on a galaxy 5 phone. I tried to change an app setting with APK from default storage to preferred external storage. I then tried to reinstall the app and it just said failed with no other explanation.

Comment: Does it require permissions which can only be granted at runtime?